# What is the best method for adding and removing entries to/from the /etc/hosts file?

Tags: shell, unix, hosts

When I'm on a work VPN I need to access a particular internal site but I need to tunnel through SSH through one of our dev servers to get to it.  This is fine.

However whenever I need to do this, I need to add an entry to the hosts file to alias this particular domain to localhost and do the SSH tunnelling, and consequently when I've finished I need to remove the entry from the hosts file.  I thought I'd automate this which is relatively easy. However managing the hosts file is not as easy as I thought:

I've tried:

```
cat /etc/hosts | grep -v 'internal.name.company.com' > /etc/hosts
```

However this always results in an empty `/etc/hosts` file.  If I run `cat /etc/hosts | grep -v 'internal.name.company.com'` I get the output I want exactly.  Am I missing something obvious?  When I redirect the output to another file, say ~/test the result is as expected and this file contains the contents I expect.

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate, my bad I didn't think of searching for that as the problem :(.  Voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: If you just have answers with 0 score, you can still delete it!

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
grep -v 'internal.name.company.com' /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts.tmp ; cp /tmp/hosts.tmp /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed` to modify the file directly:

```
sed '/internal\.name\.company\.com/d' hosts
```